# How add series dynamically in Highcharts without button? (ANGULAR JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

My issue is very specific. How I can add series dynamically in highcharts, through Angular JS, without button, otherwise, without function click.

This is my controller:

```
  var deserialize = angular.fromJson(data.dataContent); //Específico para el dataContent

    for(var i =0; i < deserialize.length; i++){

      var url = deserialize[i];

      $http.get(url).success(function(data){

        var n_scope = [];//NOMBRES PARA LA SERIE
        var e_scope = []; //EMPLEADOS

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

          var nombre_scope = n_scope.push(data[i].nombre);
          var empleados_scope = e_scope.push(parseInt(data[i].empleados));

        }

        var chart = {};

        chart.addSeries({
          name: n_scope[i],
          data: e_scope[i]
        });
```

HERE GOES THE CHART:

```
  $scope.renderChart = {
              chart: {
                  type: typeArray[2]
              },
              title: {
                   text: titleArray[2]
                   },
              xAxis:{
                categories: yAxisTiArray[2],
                title: {
                  enabled: false
                },
                labels: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              },
              yAxis:{
                title: {
                  text: yAxisTiArray[2]
                }
              },
              series: chart,
              legend: {
                  enabled: true
              },
              credits: {
                enabled: false
             },
             lang: {
               printChart: 'Imprimir gráfico',
               downloadPNG: 'Descargar en PNG',
               downloadJPEG: 'Descargar en JPG',
               downloadPDF: 'Descargar en PDF',
               downloadSVG: 'Descargar en SVG',
               contextButtonTitle: 'EXPORTAR'
             }
           };
```

I was taking this fiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/WEm4F/, but I don't want a button click function, I want that series add it to chart dynamically

Comment: When do you want that data will change? Time based?

Comment: My data is loaded from a JSON file. Every key "nombre" (spanish word for name) is the series name, and every key "empleados" (spanish word for employees) is the series data.

Comment: When I will update data in another window, should update chart when is reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****RESOLVED****

Altough have button, I could resolve this issue.

I have created a repository that integrates Angular.js, PHP, and Highcharts, with Materialize.css, adding series dynamically from external JSON.

link: https://github.com/Nullises/DynamicSeriesHighchartsAngular

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just put your code inside success blockof your API (angularjs api call ). here is an example (how I used to plot series on data change)

```
var metricData = $http.get(url);
metricData.success(function(value) {
var data = value.responseData;

var graph = [];
    angular.forEach(data.datatimeseries, function(metric) {
    graph.push([ metric.timestamp, metric.value ]);
// Assuming that datatimeseries is the timeseiries

});



var chartX = $('#yourDivId').highcharts();
chartX.addSeries({
    id : graph_id, // some id 
    data : graph 
});
setYaxisExtremes(chartX); // must use it to reflect added series
});
```